# Clickable LinearLayout in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to use LinearLayout as a button, actually I have:

```
LinearLayout Ll;
Ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MYID);
Ll.setClickable(true);
Ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //action
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work. When I try to open this activity, it gives a warning:

> Unfortunately, app has stopped

Click should close the activity and back to main. In "//action", I use `finish()` but there is the same problem.

Comment: Can I see your XML code and the error you are getting?

Comment: Are u sure it is linear layout and its id is right? Must be mistake in XML

Comment: You don't need the setClickable, true is the default.  Post the stack trace from logcat to see what the real error is.

Comment: I put id in this part of XML (there are a lot of LinearLayouts and it works if I remove codoe from first post from *.java)

Comment: <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/trainersbackbtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#B35556FF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_trainersback"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your code.

You are calling

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_trainers);
```

after the linearlayout binding with click listener.

move these as the first line of the `OnCreate`

Answer (score 0):

I put id in this part of XML (there are a lot of LinearLayouts and it works if I remove codoe from first post from *.java)

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/trainersbackbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#B35556FF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_trainersback"
                android:tint="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

May this help you,

In XML File,

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/MYID"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:focusable="true">
</LinearLayout>
```

In java code

```
LinearLayout Ll= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MYID);
Ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

and in OnBackPressed

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: When i put OnBackPresser() (copy and paste) there are errors: illegal start of expression

Comment: actually there are not errors but program still doesnt work, if I want to open this activity "Unfortunately, app has stopped"

Comment: it works fine here. May be you have some syntax error. Check for curly braces

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood but

You layout's id is trainersbackbtn

```
android:id="@+id/trainersbackbtn"
```

Then why are you calling MYID in java?

```
Ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MYID);
```

Comment: please post the whole java and xml code here or just mail me

Comment: and check the log in android monitor and tell us the exception occurs when you click the layout. It may help us.

Comment: hey listen just move that linearlayout code in your java code below   thesetContentView method

Comment: LinearLayout Ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.trainersbackbtn);
        Ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

Comment: this code below setContentView(R.layout.activity_trainers);

Comment: and also call onBackPressed() in the body of onclicklistener

Answer (score 0):

There is xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_mainback"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.szkola.dd.test1.TrainersActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_trainers">

    //info+back
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">
        //1rzad
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#D933777F"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            //zdjecie
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_mainphoto"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            //nazwa
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                //imie+nazwisko
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="25dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:text="Bartek Haliniak"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                //info o klubie
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textStyle="normal"
                            android:text="Flashdance Wrocław"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        //logout
        <LinearLayout
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:id="@+id/trainersbackbtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#B35556FF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_trainersback"
                    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    //2rzad
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#B35556FF">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_trainerstrainers"
                    android:tint="#FFFFFF"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        //trenerzy + nazwa szkoly
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="#B35556FF"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            //napis trenerzy
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:text="Trenerzy"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            //nazwa szkoly
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:text="Flashdance Wroclaw"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    //3rzad-lista
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/trainerslist">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and java code:

```
package com.szkola.dd.test1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import static android.widget.Toast.*;

public class TrainersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView listview;
    int[] list_photo = {R.drawable.alicja, R.drawable.joanna, R.drawable.ic_mainphoto, R.drawable.tomek, R.drawable.kuba};
    String[] list_name = {"Al", "J ", "Ba", "Too", "Ku"};
    String[] list_email = {"alicja@gmail.com", "joanna@wp.pl", "bartek@onet.pl", "tomek@interia.pl", "kuba@o2.pl"};
    String[] list_phone = {"759 ", "643 652 0", "67595", "612 5", "643", "573 2"};
    TrainersAdapter adapter;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LinearLayout Ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.trainersbackbtn);
        Ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trainers);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.trainerslist);
        adapter = new TrainersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_trainers);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            TrainersDataProvider dataProvider = new TrainersDataProvider(list_photo[i], list_name[i], list_email[i], list_phone[i]);
            adapter.add(dataProvider);
        }
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Trainers Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.szkola.dd.test1/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Trainers Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.szkola.dd.test1/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the linear layout without the layout being set.
Set the content first and then try to access the views. Your flow should be

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_trainers);
LinearLayout Ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.trainersbackbtn);
Ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         finish();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

From android monitor:

> 03-07 23:42:34.415 8245-8245/com.szkola.dd.test1 E/AndroidRuntime: 
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: com.szkola.dd.test1, PID: 8245
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.szkola.dd.test1/com.szkola.dd.test1.TrainersActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                              at com.szkola.dd.test1.TrainersActivity.onCreate(TrainersActivity.java:48)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>       03-07 23:42:36.363 8245-8245/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8245 SIG: 9